# Can't access friends' statuses with Facebook API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I'd like to access my friend's facebook statuses:

- I've set up an app that requests the `friends_status` permission
- Built a login page where I logged in and accepted all the permissions
- Looking at the app's permissions I see that it has the correct permission to view status updates shared with me

[image: "Status updates shared with you" permission]

- Ran this FQL to get my friends list: `select uid2 from friend where uid1 = me()` - results looked OK
- **Ran this FQL but got ZERO results:** `select uid, message from status where uid = <friends_uid>`

What am I missing?

:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunatly, you didn't miss anything. 
This is a bug, reported here:
https://developers.facebook.com/x/bugs/295677740556875/